# How to use SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST variable in yocto

Tags: build, compiler-errors, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I'll try to explain it as easy as I can. I tried to include and build package "A" in my Yocto image, but package A depends on **libftdi** and **ftdi-eeprom**. Now, "ftdi-eeprom" depends on the "libftdi".
In the newer versions of the "libftdi" the tarball also includes the ftdi-eeprom sources too and when you build the libftdi it builds both of the packages. Although because of the way that package "A" is configured I need two different recipes for each of the dependencies.

long story short, I made the two bitbake recipes as best as I could and successfully built "libftdi". Now when I run the "ftdi-eeprom" recipe, it wants to populate some files into the sysroot that are already installed there by libftdi. Here is where the error occurs... duplicates!

Apparently I need to set a **SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST** variable and declare that these duplicate files are safe to replace the old ones in the image (this overwrite must happen). Can someone please help me with configuring the SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST? I am not that pro working with Yocto.

Errors that I get on screen are uploaded in [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/47hfji8k8m7qdvr/populate_error.txt?dl=0)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to not use SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST for this at all. Instead, in the libftdi recipe's do_install (or do_install_append, if the recipe itself doesn't define its own do_install) you should delete the duplicate files from within ${D} and then they won't get staged and the error won't occur.

Comment: Yes, either delete the colliding files, or have one recipe build everything, and the just put the eeprom-files in its own package. (I haven't looked at the recipe in question, but this might be an even better approach).

Comment: Thank you for the reply guys, I'm just starting to use Yocto and I'm still learning. Can I trouble you for a sample syntax of what you proposed to do? It would really help. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using:
SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST = "/"

Dont forget the quotes. Here's my bb excerpt:

```
SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST = "/"

DEPENDS = ""

do_unpack() {
    mkdir -pv ${S}
    tar xvf ${DL_DIR}/${FILENAME}.tar  -C ${S}
}

do_install() {
    install -d -m 755  ${D}${includedir}
    install -m 644  ${S}/${MYPATH}/inc/myHeader1.h ${D}${includedir}
    install -m 644  ${S}/${MYPATH}/inc/myHeader2.h ${D}${includedir}
    install -m 644  ${S}/${MYPATH}/inc/myHeader3.h ${D}${includedir}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by adding the SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST to the bitbake recipe of the package as follows:

SSTATE_DUPWHITELIST = "${TMPDIR}/PATH/TO/THE/FILES"

I added the absolute path of all of the 6,7 files that had the conflict to the list. I did that because they were basically coming from a same source and it was all safe to do that. correct me if there is a better way though.

Hope this helps someone!